# Something screwy going on in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{51}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{6}]$, I can readily find that $(-1)(2 - \sqrt{6})(2 + \sqrt{6}) = 2$ and $(3 - \sqrt{6})(3 + \sqrt{6}) = 3$. It looks strange but it checks out.

But when I try the same thing for $3$ and $17$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{51}]$ I seem to run into a wall. I can't solve $x^2 - 51y^2 = \pm3$ in integers, nor $x^2 - 51y^2 = \pm17$. I've had six decades in which to get rusty at solving equations in two variables, so maybe I have managed to overlook solutions to both of these. Or could it really be possible that $3$ and $17$ are actually irreducible in this domain?

Comment: Those numbers may well remain prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{51}]$.  There's no reason they have to factor.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says there are no integer solutions, and I see no reason to expect there to be or for those numbers to factor.

Comment: @Gregory But they both divide the discriminant, don't they?

Comment: I'm not sure but anyway why do they necessaryly factor as $(x+\sqrt{51}y)(x-\sqrt{51}y)$?  Should it be $(a+b\sqrt{51})(c+d\sqrt{51})$

Comment: Following the procedure outlined at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) shows that there is no solution to $x^2-51y^2 = \pm 3$. I didn't check $\pm 17$, which is more complicated since $17 > \sqrt{51}$.

Comment: Ok I looked it up, if $p$ divides the discriminant then its ideal $(p)$ should factor into the square of a prime ideal $\mathcal o^2=(p)$.  So I guess that means $(2-\sqrt6)=(2+\sqrt6)$ as prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{6}}2]$.

Comment: There is a procedure for finding all numbers of modest absolute value represented by a form such as $x^2 - 51 y^2,$ given in chapter I of http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf and many of my answers. I, eventually, wrote C++ programs that just tell me what numbers are represented up to some bound. Used for my answer.

Comment: @Greg If $a, b, c, d$ are all nonzero, then $(a + b\sqrt{51})(c + d\sqrt{51}) = ac + (ad + bc)\sqrt{51} + 51bd$. Thus you need $bc = -ad$ for the $\sqrt{51}$ part of this to zero out and produce a rational integer.

Comment: Loved the title. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both your equations can be transformed to $3u^2-17v^2=\pm1$ (because one of $x,y$ must be a multiple of $3$ resp. $17$). Then 
$$-u^2-v^2\equiv \pm1\pmod4 $$
is impossible with the plus sign and
$$v^2\equiv \pm1\pmod3 $$
is impossible with the minus sign. Hence there is no solution.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: it may be best to give the four classes as $x^2 - 51 y^2,$  $3 x^2 - 17 y^2,$ $-x^2 + 51 y^2,$ $-3 x^2 + 17 y^2.$ Indeed, it is central to Dirichlet's approach to the composition of binary quadratic forms is that a form $x^2 + AB y^2$ leads to the form $A x^2 + B y^2,$ which is probably not equivalent to the original.

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{By the pricking of my thumb,}\cr
\text{Something wicked 51.}\end{array}$$

ORIGINAL: $x^2 - 51 y^2$ does not represent $\pm 3$ or $\pm 17.$ Instead, $3 x^2 + 12 xy - 5 y^2$ represents both $3$ and $-17,$ the latter with $(x=-2,y=1).$ Oh, $x^2 - 51 y^2$ is $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $ x^2 + 14 xy - 2 y^2.$ The four classes of binary forms of the discriminant are below, these are combined into two ideals as forms 1,2 are combined, 3,4 are combined. In case of curiosity, see http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/   Oh, one simple theorem that can be used here: for binary forms of some discriminant (here $204$) that is not a square, any given prime is integrally represented by at most one form of that discriminant and its "opposite" class, should those be distinct, and the same comment applies to representing $-p.$ The principal form (represents $1$) is always equivalent to its opposite, and we can tell that the same applies to $3 x^2 + 12 xy - 5 y^2$ because $3$ divides $12,$ that is actually the definition of "ambiguous." Same for forms numbered 2,4.

```
204    factored   2^2 * 3 *  17

    1.             1          14          -2   cycle length             2
    2.            -1          14           2   cycle length             2
    3.             3          12          -5   cycle length             6
    4.            -3          12           5   cycle length             6

  form class number is   4

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus



=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

           1          14          -2   original form
 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

           1 =  1 
          13 = 13
          21 = 3 * 7
          25 = 5^2
          30 = 2 * 3 * 5
          49 = 7^2
          70 = 2 * 5 * 7
          85 = 5 * 17
          93 = 3 * 31
          94 = 2 * 47


 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

          -1          14           2   original form
 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

           2 = 2
          15 = 3 * 5
          26 = 2 * 13
          35 = 5 * 7
          42 = 2 * 3 * 7
          47 = 47
          50 = 2 * 5^2
          51 = 3 * 17
          59 = 59
          83 = 83
          87 = 3 * 29
          98 = 2 * 7^2


 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
           3          12          -5   original form
 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

           3 = 3
           7 = 7
          10 = 2 * 5
          31 = 31
          34 = 2 * 17
          39 = 3 * 13
          58 = 2 * 29
          75 = 3 * 5^2
          79 = 79
          82 = 2 * 41
          91 = 7 * 13


 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

          -3          12           5   original form
 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100

           5 = 5
           6 = 2 * 3
          14 = 2 * 7
          17 = 17
          29 = 29
          41 = 41
          62 = 2 * 31
          65 = 5 * 13
          78 = 2 * 3 * 13


 Primitively represented positive integers up to  100
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

Answer (score 6):

There is one crucial difference between $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{51}]$: one is a unique factorization domain, the other is not. You have to accept that some of the tools that come in so handy in UFDs are just not as useful in non-UFDs.

One of those tools is the Legendre symbol. Given distinct primes $p, q, r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$ is a unique factorization domain, then $\left(\frac{pq}{r}\right)$ reliably tells you whether $r$ is reducible or irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$. Also, both $p$ and $q$ are composite, because otherwise you'd have $pq$ and $(\sqrt{pq})^2$ as valid distinct factorizations of $pq$, contradicting that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$ is a unique factorization domain.

Of course if $\left(\frac{pq}{r}\right) = -1$, then $r$ is irreducible regardless of the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$. But if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$ has class number 2 or greater, then a lot of expectations break down. It can happen that $\left(\frac{pq}{r}\right) = 1$ and yet $r$ is nonetheless irreducible, e.g., $\left(\frac{51}{5}\right) = 1$, yet 5 is irreducible.

And it can also happen in a non-UFD that $pq$ and $(\sqrt{pq})^2$ are both valid distinct factorizations of $pq$. This is by no means unique to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{51}]$. It happens with 2 and 5 in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, 3 and 5 in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$, 2 and 13 in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{26}]$, etc. In fact, I'd be very surprised if someone showed me an example of a non-UFD $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$ in which both $p$ and $q$ are composite.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{55}]$?

Comment: Give me some time to think about that one...